# Add ToolTip to DataTemplate in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, tooltip, treeviewitem

I'm trying to add a tooltip to children in a TreeView in WPF. However, it appears even in the XAML I can't get a tooltip to render in the treeview children. Can someone please tell me how to get around this?

```
<Window x:Class="Client_Invoice_Auditor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client_Invoice_Auditor"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:Client_Invoice_Auditor.CoreClientAR"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Client Invoice Auditor" Height="450" Width="1000">
    <Window.Resources>
        <self:SPConverter x:Key="SPConverter"/>
        <self:ErrorExpandConverter x:Key="ErrorExpandConverter"/>
        <self:AssignRowConverter x:Key="AssignRowConverter"/>
        <self:IssueIconConverter x:Key="IssueIconConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDeitions>

        </Grid.ColumnDeitions>
        <Grid.RowDeitions>
            <RowDeition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDeition Height="80*"/>
        </Grid.RowDeitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                    <Menu Name="fileMenu" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <MenuItem Header="File">
                            <MenuItem Header="Open Account File" Click="menuOpenFile_Click"/>

                            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="menuExit_Click"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Options">
                            <!--<MenuItem Header="Update" Click="update_Click"/>-->
                            <MenuItem Header="About" Click="about_Click"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </DockPanel>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Border BorderBrush="MediumAquamarine" BorderThickness="2">
                            <Label Name="AccountNumber"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="MediumAquamarine" BorderThickness="2">
                            <Label Name="AcctDesc"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border BorderBrush="MediumAquamarine" BorderThickness="2">
                            <Label Name="Organization"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </WrapPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Label Margin="20,10,0,0" Content="Activity Date Time" />
                    <Label Margin="60,10,0,0" Content="Beginning Balance" />
                    <Label Margin="10,10,0,0" Content="Charge Amount" />
                    <Label Margin="30,10,0,0" Content="Adjustments" />
                    <Label Margin="40,10,0,0" Content="Payments" />
                    <Label Margin="60,10,0,0" Content="End Balance" />
                    <Label Margin="50,10,0,0" Content="Issues" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid Name="IssuesGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDeitions>
                    <!--<ColumnDeition Width="80*"/>-->
                    <!--<ColumnDeition Width="20*"/>-->
                </Grid.ColumnDeitions>
                <TreeView Name="View">
                    <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" 
                                                Value="{Binding Class, Converter={StaticResource ErrorExpandConverter}}" />
                    </Style>-->
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" 
                                                Value="{Binding Dummies, Converter={StaticResource ErrorExpandConverter}}" />
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:dailyAccountBalance}" ItemsSource="{Binding Dummies}">

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Row="{Binding RowIndex}" ToolTip="This info">
                                    <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{Binding ActivityDate}" />
                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding BegBalance}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ChrgAmount}" />
                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding AdjAmount}" />
                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding PmtAmount}" />
                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding EndBalance}" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="True" ToolTipService.ToolTip="This balance thing" ToolTip="This balance"/>

                                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="100" ToolTip="This">
                                    <ContentControl.Content>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IssueIconConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="RowIndex"/>
                                            <Binding Path="Errors"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </ContentControl.Content>
                                    <!--<TextBlock Text="Test"/>-->

                                </ContentControl>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:DummyItem}">

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />-->
                                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ChargeActivities}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                                            <DataGrid.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count,
                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  Value="0">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGrid.Style>

                                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ChrgID"  Header=" Charge" Binding="{Binding ChargeID}" />
                                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ChrgType"  Header="Charge Type" Binding="{Binding ChargeType}">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="CR">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                                                </Trigger>
                                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ChrgAmt"  Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding ChargeAmount}">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ChargeType}" Value="CR">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name=""  Header="" Binding="{Binding Stuff}" />
                                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Class"  Header=" Class" Binding="{Binding Class}">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Class, Converter={StaticResource SPConverter}}"/>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                                        </DataGrid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                        <!--<TreeViewItem x:Key="Test">
                            <TextBlock Text="Me gusta"></TextBlock>
                        </TreeViewItem>-->
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any suggestions to get tooltips to render in the treeview children would definitely be appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the tooltip property of elements inside of the template, you set it on the TreeViewItem itself.

Here is a very simplified example:

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item #1" DataContext="Test1" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item #2" DataContext="Test2" />
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Here I had to set the DataContext manually and hardcoded for the example to work since just using the Header property doesn't set it, but in the real world, you are going to be data bound, so it will be set.

Comment: TreeView doesn't doesn't have the ability to initialize with tooltips until you loaded the window...

Comment: @KieranOjakangas TreeViewItem has a ToolTip property that you can set in various ways. Hard code, binding, etc. Really depends what you want to display in it. It's an object, so you can put anything you want in there and customize it with a DataTemplate too.

Comment: @KieranOjakangas one easy way based on your example is to put a style that targets TreeViewItem inside of TreeView.Resources and set the ToolTip property through binding to something in the item itself so as the title.

Comment: Yeah. See here's the thing - everything populated in my tree with converters, etc. But I can't get the tooltip to populate inside the TreeView item's contents. How would I do that?

Comment: @KieranOjakangas As I said, you wouldn't. You set the tooltip on the TreeViewItem itself. I've updated my answer to give you a simplified example. Since my simplified example is not data bound, I had to force the DataContext, but in a bound scenario, you can bind to anything in the DataContext.

Comment: @KieranOjakangas for your example, you are sticking a DataGrid in each TreeViewItem? So you want a different tooltip for each cell in the DataGrid?

Comment: That sucks... I'm trying to assign a tooltip to images added dynamically to a Content control in my TreeView Item based on the images populated... I'm using a value converter for that...

Comment: @KieranOjakangas You mean the IssueIconConverter portion? Is that returning an ImageSource?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184574/discussion-between-kieran-ojakangas-and-sledgehammer).